# Why does my Hindu Temple ring its bell so loud for so long?

Tags: temple, kali

I stay next to a Hindu temple dedicated to goddess Kali. On its rooftop, there is a gigantic bell. The bell is rang every morning at 8am, at noon time and around 6pm. Each session lasting a good 12 minutes. Is there a good reason for such loud and long lasting chime? I need to know the background behind the din because it affects the tranquility of my neighborhood and I wanted to talk to the temple people to seek a peaceful resolution.

Comment: In which city is the temple located?

Comment: So the question is - Why ringing lasts longer? It has nothing to do with Hinduism.

Comment: Just focus on the sound and vibration of the bell without any negative feelings for those twelve minutes. If you still get irritated you may have a chat with the priest and even if that does not work cotton wool for your ears might help.   If you decide to stay near any temple this is something you have to deal with. It is always recommended to build temples with enough free space outside, but in this day and age nobody follows any rules.

Comment: Where do you live? There are no such rules for Hindu temples afaik.

Comment: They ring it to remind you to think about God.

Comment: @The Destroyer and Rickross, I am presently staying at an apartment in Singapore. If there are no rules then perhaps you could provide an answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Ringing a bell produces auspicious sound which cancels the negative vibrations around us, if present.

It is also used to match our body's natural frequency and the specific vibration in the Sun's Coronal loops (found by human race till now scientifically.  Should be present everywhere).

[https://www.quora.com/Is-it-true-that-NASA-has-recently-found-that-the-sound-from-the-sun-resembles-the-Vedic-mantra-Om][1]]

Also during Aarti, the bell, drum and conch are sounded to drown other worldly disturbances, calm one’s thoughts and to facilitate one’s senses and mind to focus on god.

The unique sound of bell removes tension and negativity from our mind and creates unity of our left and right brain.

Bell produces sharp echo sound which activates seven healing centres or chakras in your body as it does during meditation.

It produces sound of “OM” which is actually the sound of universe. This attract all positive cosmic energies from the atmosphere which will help us live better.

Comment: Quora is not an authentic source. Please visit [Guidelines for new users answering questions](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/125/3500)

Comment: I am asking whether there is any significance to the loudness, duration and timing in Hinduism.

Comment: Every pooja or aarthi will take approximately from 10 to 15 minutes to get completed.  At that time the bell will be rang.   In some places it may be for more duration according to the pooja performed.  As said earlier it is to make everybody focus.